# Setting up NHibernate with local Db in VS

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am setting a new project in VS using NHibernate as ORM.
I just try to verify my configuration code by inserting new object into table.

**My model xml for NH mapper :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHTest"
                   namespace="NHTest">

  <class name="Product">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Category" />
    <property name="Discontinued" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Model .cs :**

```
namespace NHTest
{
        public class Product
        {
            virtual public Guid Id { get; set; }
            virtual public string Name { get; set; }
            virtual public string Category { get; set; }
            virtual public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
        }
}
```

**Sample code :**

```
    var configuartion = new Configuration();
    configuartion.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
    {
        x.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
        x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
        x.Dialect<MsSqlCeDialect>();
    });
        configuartion.AddAssembly("NHTest");
        var sessionFactory = configuartion.BuildSessionFactory();
        var os = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        os.Save(new Product()
       {
           Category = "X",
           Discontinued = true,
           Name = "Radek"

       });
       os.Flush();
```

**Questions** :

1)Why flush method return exception "could insert into db ..."?

2)Is it related to configuration of db ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

> generator class="identity"

to

> generator class="guid.comb"

You cannot do identity inserts with Guids, they need to be generated client side, guid.comb will generate a guid for you.